# Changed Late 2011 Macbook Pro HDD to SSD, Won't Boot

Tags: ssd, osx-el-capitan

I've recently bought a Sandisk Ultra II 480GB SSD to replace the HDD in my late 2011 Macbook Pro.

The steps that I've been through are:

1. Install Carbon Copy Clone (CCC)
2. Attach SSD via USB-SATA to USB drive
3. Clone the HDD onto the SSD
4. Reboot Holding the Option key (SSD still connected via USB).
5. Select SSD as the boot drive
6. Success! It boots via USB and is even pretty speedy.
7. Shutdown, remove case, remove existing HDD, install SSD
8. Power On, nothing! Just a blank white screen.

Did I miss any steps?

Update:

So I was in a rush when I swapped the drives this morning, excited that the copy had finished I wanted to do the swap before going to work.

The next steps I did to get it working were:

9. Start the machine with Option held down.
10. Select boot from the SSD.
11. Login, and search for Startup Disk.
12. Click the lock, then click on your SSD, then click the lock again.

Done. I wish I'd done this upgrade years ago, it's so much faster.

Comment: Swapping back to the old drive will still boot? Just to eliminate a cable issue. I'm not sure how to test for this, but some USB enclosures intercept the drive & change the apparent block size; eliminating the enclosure effectively 'breaks' the drive.

Comment: I've not tried that yet, I will try when I get home and report back